# How to programmatically look at the VBA code of old Access databases?

Tags: c#, vba, ms-access

To facilitate a move to a Windows 10 and Office 365 environment, I have a requirement to write a program (in C# or VB.NET) that will read the VBA code of older Access databases (anything from 2003 up) and look for specific snippets of code and if possible, change that code and save. This needs to be performed on around 500 Access databases.

I've done this before in Word and Excel without much trouble, but I just can't seem to get it to work for Access.

I've tried it like this:

```
var appClass = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
appClass.OpenCurrentDatabase(thefilepath, false, "");
var dbs = appClass.CurrentProject;
foreach (AccessObject myMods in dbs.AllModules)
{
    //Look at the module here and look at the code
}
```

And like this:

```
accessApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.ApplicationClass();
accessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(inputMdb, false, password);
foreach (Access.AccessObject obj in accessApp.CurrentProject.AllModules)
{
    //Look at the module here and look at the code
}
```

But I get errors like:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The expression you
> entered refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exist.'

For the life of me, I can't get this to work and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about `AccessObject` or if that even works with other MS-Office programs but the way I used to access modules is via `VBProject.VBComponents`.

The following should work:

```
using Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;
using MSAccess = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access;

//...

var accessApp = new MSAccess.Application();
accessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(inputMdb, false, password);
foreach (VBComponent vbc in accessApp.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents)
{
    var module = vbc.CodeModule;

    // To print all code in the file:
    Console.WriteLine(module.Lines[1, module.CountOfLines]);

    // To export to file:
    vbc.Export(somePath);

    // To insert code:
    module.InsertLines(4, newLineOfCode);

    // To replace code:
    module.ReplaceLine(5, modifiedLineOfCode);
}

accessApp.CloseCurrentDatabase();
accessApp.Quit();
```

Comment: Dude, your a lifesaver! I tried your code and it works great....but....
I used 'module.Replaceline(linenumber,modifiedcode)' and then immediatly ran 'Console.WriteLine(module.Lines[1, module.CountOfLines]);' to check the change and it was there (brilliant), but when I stopped and re-ran the code the change was gone. It look like the change wasn't saved. I looked for a save function but couldn't find one. Do you know what I'm missing ?

Comment: @Kevin Changes to the code seem to be saved automatically for me. Are you sure your database file isn't read-only? If it's not, maybe try calling `accessApp.DoCmd.Save(MSAccess.AcObjectType.acModule, module.Name);` inside the loop and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Found the problem, on this line 
"accessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(inputMdb, **false**, password);". The false is the bool that sets exclusive access, and it needs to be true. Changing that AND using you suggestion of "accessApp.DoCmd.Save" solved it.
Thank you very much for your help :)